# Tiebreaker criterion of the mode() in postgres

Tags: postgresql

When using the `mode()` aggregation function, which tiebreaker criterion does the method use?

```
 select  mode() within group (order by my_field) FROM my_table
```

I couldn't find any documentation related to that

What happens if the column has an equal amount of occurrence of the values

```
select my_field, count(*) FROM my_table group by 1
```

| status | count |
| --- | --- |
| 4096 | 24 |
| 4098 | 24 |

In this example above, I am getting **4096**, but I would like to confirm if it actually gets the lowest result, or if this is happening for another reason

UPDATE:

I still don't know how to fix this so that it's not an arbitrary choice, for now I'm using another order by

```
select  mode() within group (order by my_field) FROM my_table order by my_field
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, it is arbitrary:

> mode () WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY anyelement ) → anyelement
>
> Computes the mode, the most frequent value of the aggregated argument
> (arbitrarily choosing the first one if there are multiple
> equally-frequent values). The aggregated argument must be of a
> sortable type.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE

Comment: so... a SORT BY should fix it?

Comment: @Guilherme I would imagine so.